# Loop and Set through variable in a Class in C# that is used multiple times

Tags: c#, class, iteration

I Have a class `TrayDetails` containing a bunch of variables.

```
public class TrayDetails
{
    public string ID { get; set;}
    //... some more string variables here
}
```

Then I declared it on my main form twice.

```
private TrayDetails Right;
private TrayDetails Left;
```

I would want to iterate through the specific `Right` or `Left` variables and set all of its variables to `string.empty` when a condition is met.

Code:

```
Action FillData = () =>
{
     if(Right != null)
     {
        this.label1.Text = Right.ID;
        //... somemore labels = Right.somevariables
     }
     else
     {
         //I would want to put the string.empty variables here using a loop.
         //I cant seem to get PropertyInfo to work
     }

     //similar as above
     if(Left != null)
     // you get the idea
}
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: If `Right == null`, how would you set the properties on an object that doesn't exist? If you need to instantiate `Right` in that `else` block, I would simply have its constructor set the property values to `string.Empty`. Your code would become much simpler.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Well I can do that. but my existing code on setting the values in my `Right` or `Left` is generic. Sample: `details.Add(new TrayDetails() {OrderNo = dr.GetString(0)}`

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, you want to set `Text` property of all (Form)controls to *empty* `string` when the `Right/Left` objects are `null`

You could do this using `Linq`

```
this.Controls
       .OfType<Control>()  // Apply filter, if only for specific controls.
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(x=> x.Text = string.Empty);
```

Comment: This would be my answer but not all of my labels in my form should be set to `string.Empty`

Comment: I mentioned that point as a comment, you could simply apply where condition. You're in better position to say which controls are required and what is exact filter criteria :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend refactoring this so that the controls are set using a common method. For example, something like this:

```
private SetupLabels(TrayDetails trayDetails)
{
    this.label1.Text = (trayDetails != null) ? trayDetails.Id : string.Empty;
    // Set more labels here
}
```

Using this approach, you could then have the following:

```
Action FillData = () =>
{
    SetupLabels(Right);
    SetupLabels(Left);
}
```

Note, this won't work quite right as you're setting the same labels in both cases, so if your `Right` property is not null, the labels will be set, and then if the `Left` property is also not null, it will change the labels again, so you'll need to modify this a bit.

The idea is the same though, where you have a common method that sets your controls and takes an instance of `TrayDetails`.  If you're trying to setup the controls in a specific part of your page, you can wrap them in a container, and then update the `SetupLabels` method to take the container name.

Assuming you're using WebForms, you could use something like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="LeftContainer" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" />
    <!--Other controls-->
</asp:PlaceHolder>

<asp:PlaceHolder id="RightContainer" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" />
    <!--Other controls-->
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

The SetupLabels method could then look like this:

```
private SetupLabels(TrayDetails trayDetails, string containerName)
{
    PlaceHolder container = (PlaceHolder) Page.FindControl(containerName);
    ((Label) container.FindControl("label1")).Text = (trayDetails != null) ? trayDetails.Id : string.Empty;
    // Set more labels here
}
```

It's still a bit of a messy solution, but gives you fine control over exactly how the labels are populated from the TrayDetails object.